# How to send multiple objects from jsp files

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to send multiple objects from jsp file using commandname in spring form

I have searched on google and explored various sites but found no solutions of this problem

```
<form:form action="addproductLED"method="post"commandname="addProductLed"> 
<div align="center">
<h2 class="ledtechdetails">Add Led</h2>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:25px;margin-bottom:25px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" class="addledtable">
<tr  class="add-led">
<td class="add-led">Product Category :</td>
<td class="add-led">
<select id="productCatId"name="productCatId"class="protechname"onchange="showled('led')" required>
</tr>
<tr  class="add-led">
<td  class="add-led">Product Name :</td>
<td  class="add-led">
<input type="text" name="productName" required class="protechname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr  class="add-led">
<td class="add-led">Product Stock :</td>
<td class="add-led"><input type="number" name="productStock" required class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Product SKU :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="text" name="productsku" required class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Product MRP :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="number" name="productMrp" required class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Product Price :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="number" name="productprize" required class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
                <td class="add-led">Product Size :</td>
                <td class="add-led"><input type="text" name="productsize"  class="protechname"/></td>
            </tr>
 <!-- another model class configuration --> 

 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Resolution :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="text" name="resolution" class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Port :</td>
 <td class="add-led">
 <input type="text" name="port"  class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Wifi Type :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="text" name="type"  class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr class="add-led">
 <td class="add-led">Operating System :</td>
 <td class="add-led"><input type="text" name="operatingSystem" class="protechname"/></td>
 </tr>
```

I want to get model class object in Spring Controller but I dont know how to send two model class object from one single jsp page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include multiple model element in spring form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176677/how-to-include-multiple-model-element-in-spring-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transfer multiple objects using commandname separated by semi-colon,

You have to change

```
<form:form action="addproductLED"method="post"commandname="addProductLed">
```

to

```
<form:form action="addproductLED" method="post" commandname="addProductLed,anotherObject" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

It will send multiple object.